# Convert resource dialog form to source code

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, user-interface

Is there some automated way to convert the declarative `.rc` dialog definition format (and its content) to snippets of source code that invoke runtime APIs like `CreateWindow` to create a dialog with the same layout and content?  Ideally from within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog resources do not generate code. They are passed to [`CreateDialogIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645436.aspx) and similar API's that interpret the [`DLGTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645394.aspx) and construct individual controls calling `CreateWindow`.

There are no tools that convert a dialog resource script to a redundant sequence of `CreateWindow` calls. The only use for a `DLGTEMPLATE` is to be passed to `CreateDialogIndirect`.

Comment: Why is calling sequence of CreateWindow commands redundant if developing Win32 native applications using VS?

Comment: @RawN It's redundant code, since `CreateDialogIndirect` already implements all the functionality you want. And some, that you're not even aware of, namely, scaling the dialog relative to the dialog font in use.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My original question was edited. My intention was to use the dialog box as a main window in a way that I design the about box in the designer and convert it somehow to a series of CreateWindow calls and put that inside a WM_CREATE message but I see that's not possible.

Comment: @RawN There's nothing that prevents a dialog from being an application's main window. Instead of calling `CreateWindow` for your main window, you simply call `CreateDialog` and adjust your window procedure implementation to comply to a [`DialogProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx). I don't see how `WM_CREATE` is involved here at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks man! That's what I wanted. Is this approach considered to be bad practice?

Comment: @RawN Not at all. It's the prescribed solution to implementing a dialog-based application. A dialog box is implemented using the regular windowing APIs, with a few extras, such as keyboard navigation. [Dialog Box Programming Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644995.aspx) documents the few areas that are different between regular windows and dialog boxes, and how to adapt to them.